# Diagnosing Stormy Waters

Tags: wordplay

Lately I've been terribly sad, sleepy, can't eat. I have bouts of insomnia, I can't concentrate, I have trouble remembering... what are those things?
Oh yes, Details!

I also recently lost my house when a hurricane leveled my neighborhood.

I went to my psychiatrist and he diagnosed me with...

**What**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

> Tropical Depression

Because:

> All of the symptoms are associated with depression and a hurricane grows out of (and weakens to) a tropical depression.

Comment: I'm happy that you got it, but don't have the energy to move my arms in a clapping motion just yet.